# How do I access a Service Application field in Central Admin using CSOM from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, csom, central-administration, service-application

In Central Admin you go to Service Applications and you will see a list of applications. For example: Access Services 2010.

[image]

When you click Access Services 2010 a list of fields is displayed as shown below:

[image]

In this example, we have the field 'Maximum Columns Per Query'. Is it possible to access a field value for a service application using CSOM from JavaScript?

Comment: You can't. Use PowerShell for this. Or, do this in a web service hosted on the server and query it using javascript.

Comment: Thanks @Akhoy. If you could put that in an answer then I'll give you my vote.